# Remove nginx password from main site

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver

So I have a website running and i'm using nginx, I use a password to protect directories so they are not public. I figured out how to make them not have a password using

```
    location ^~ /public {
            auth_basic off;
            autoindex on;
            allow all;
    }
```

This allows for my public directory not to have a password but I can't figure out how to make my root dir, /var/www, not have a password.